# $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is closed iff $\sup(A\cap[a,b])\in A$ and $\inf(A\cap[a,b])\in A$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose that $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Show that the following are equivalent:

(a) $A$ is closed.

(b) If $[a,b]$ is a closed interval for which $A\cap[a,b]$ is non-empty, then $\sup(A\cap[a,b])\in A$ and $\inf(A\cap[a,b])\in A$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let us prove the implication $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$ first.

Since $A\cap[a,b]$ is non-empty and bounded above by $b$, it admits a supremum.

Moroever, we do also have that $A\cap[a,b]\subseteq A$. Hence we conclude
\begin{align*}
\sup(A\cap[a,b])\in\overline{A\cap[a,b]}\subseteq\overline{A} = A \Rightarrow \sup(A\cap[a,b])\in A
\end{align*}

This is because the supremum of a set is a closure point of it. Similar reasoning applies to the infimum.

However I do not know how to approach the converse implication.

Could someone tell me what I am missing?

Any contribution is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: Suppose $A$ is not closed. Then, there exists some converging (and WLOG monotonic) sequence $x_1,x_2,\dots\in A\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=x\not\in A$. Take $[a,b]=[x-1,x]$ if the sequence is increasing, or $[a,b]=[x,x+1]$ if it is deceasing, and observe...

(comment if more detail is needed!)

Comment: It's not correct that you can necessarily find such a sequence that's increasing.  Suppose $A=(0, 1]$.  But you can necessarily find a strictly monotonic sequence, and with a little care, that's good enough.

Comment: That's why I said WLOG increasing, the idea is the same, but I will edit, good point